# Understanding MongoDB references

Tags: mongodb

I read about data-models in MongoDB and came to [one to many relationship](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#data-modeling-publisher-and-books):

In the following example, does it mean the book-documents should be in the collection `books` and MongoDB will somehow link the documents with ids matching the array `books` to the `publisher`? Or does the link exists only in the architector's head?

```
{
   name: "O'Reilly Media",
   founded: 1980,
   location: "CA",
   books: [12346789, 234567890, ...]
}

{
    _id: 123456789,
    title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
    author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
    published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
    pages: 216,
    language: "English"
}

{
   _id: 234567890,
   title: "50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developer",
   author: "Kristina Chodorow",
   published_date: ISODate("2011-05-06"),
   pages: 68,
   language: "English"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB **isn't** going to somehow link the documents with `ids` matching the array books to the `publisher`. So yes **the link exists only in the architect's head**

The article is simply trying to explain how a one to many relationship can be formulated between documents in MongoDB.

`One to many` relationship in MongoDB is also **further classified** as `one to few` and `one to squillions`. If the scenario is `one to few`, an approach like this can be used:

```
{
    name: "O'Reilly Media",
    founded: 1980,
    location: "CA",
    books: [12346789, 234567890, ...]
} {
    _id: 123456789,
    title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
    author: ["Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf"],
    published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
    pages: 216,
    language: "English"
} {
    _id: 234567890,
    title: "50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developer",
    author: "Kristina Chodorow",
    published_date: ISODate("2011-05-06"),
    pages: 68,
    language: "English"
}
```

But in real a publisher could have millions of books published. So in that case it would be an example of one to squillions. Now storing millions of `book_ids` may make a MongoDB Document exceed the size of 16MB which is limit to the size a MongoDB Document can have. So in that case it's better to use this approach:

```
{
    _id: "oreilly",
    name: "O'Reilly Media",
    founded: 1980,
    location: "CA"
} {
    _id: 123456789,
    title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
    author: ["Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf"],
    published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
    pages: 216,
    language: "English",
    publisher_id: "oreilly"
} {
    _id: 234567890,
    title: "50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developer",
    author: "Kristina Chodorow",
    published_date: ISODate("2011-05-06"),
    pages: 68,
    language: "English",
    publisher_id: "oreilly"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are called manual references in [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) and are the preferred method for relations. There is also DBRef, but as the documentation states you shoud use manual references:

> In most cases you should use the manual reference method for
>   connecting two or more related documents. However, if you need to
>   reference documents from multiple collections, consider using DBRefs.

Neither method really links anything in the DB level.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning DBRefs!

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB itself, it is not possible as far as I know, but in MongooseJS, the javascript wrapper around MongoDB it is possible by saving the reference to the book._id in the publisher.books array.

```
var publisherSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  founded     : Number,
  books : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Book' }]
});

var bookSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  title    : String,
  author    : [{type: String}],
  pages: Number,
  language: String
});

var Book  = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);
var Publisher = mongoose.model('Publisher', publisherSchema);
```

When querying the data, you can then use the populate method.

```
Publisher.
    find().
    populate('books')
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! So when they bothered to implement it, than I'm not the only one missing the references.